# Non-commutative Leibniz rule

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

The Leibniz formula tell us what to do with higher derivatives of products of functions. For example:

$\frac{d^n}{dt^n} \left( f(t)g(t) \right)$.

What should I be thinking when I have a similar situation but with two 4x4 square, complex matrix valued functions $A,B$:

$\frac{d^n}{dt^n} \left( A(t)B(t) \right)$.

Comment: I think it would be the same: $(AB)'=AB'+A'B$. But you might want to use the limit definition of derivative to make sure. (I doubt the proof would be much different than the commutative case.)

Comment: The non-commutativity of the product doesn't play any role here. It's if it was the addition that was not commutative that there would be a problem

Comment: So no collection of 'like terms' has happened to prove this formula:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: @Benjamin, why don't you try proving it?!

Comment: I got it now thanks. I just always, incorrectly, assumed that the terms had been grouped in some way to produce the binomial coefficients. But no.